# How to run a gui from another gui tab in matlab?

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

I am unsure of how to call up and run a separate GUI from my main GUI homepage. I am able to open it using uiopen(' ') but I am trying to get it to automatically run it if possible. I've created all of the GUI pages and I have set up the callbacks but I cant get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

every GUI has a guifile.m, so you can just call the name of the 2nd GUI.

for example, assuming you have two GUIs, `gui1.{m,fig}` and `gui2.{m,fig}`. In the `OnButtonClick` even in your `gui1.m`, you just call `gui2` to open up the gui2 window.